# Props and share data between components in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, native

What is the best practice to send data between 2 components ?

For clearly understand, I have A component that inside he render 2 components B and C.
I need to share text Input data on change that user write in B and show it in C .

I tried it in 2 ways,
In the successfully but ugly I set
const [ data,setData ] = useState(“”)  in A and send on props to B to “setData” on change , and the “data” to C.

and the other that work just after click on C component and not on change text is with redux , I try to save every change on redux.

Is someone knew what is the best way for resolve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a good alternative to Redux is [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

> Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.

It seems that the React Context Api is the all that you need to do it.

Also, check this good tutorial to get more info about it.
[Learn React Context in 5 Minutes - A Beginner's Tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-context-in-5-minutes/)

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you ! This is exactly what I needed